# How to compare two indices with different formulations?

Tags: agreement-statistics, hypothesis-testing

The experiment I am performing requires comparison of a physical property (such as shear modulus $M$) of two regions of a sample (say left and right regions). Smaller the differences, more would be the degree of homogeneity of the sample.

To compare the modulus of the left and right regions, the standard practice in my field is to take the ratio of the modulus of the left and right sections. To compare different samples, more the ratio is near to 1, better the homogeneity. The equation below shows the approach to determine the index of homogeneity ($IH_1$):

$$
IH_1 = \frac{M_{left}}{M_{right}}
$$

In my research, I am trying a different approach. I use the maximum of the left and right moduli and the average of the two moduli, and use the following equation to report $IH_2$:

$$
IH_2 = \frac{M_{max}-M_{avg}}{M_{avg}}
$$

A lower value of $IH_2$ is desirable for a better homogeneity (ideal value is 0).

I have results of the two indices at forty temperatures for four samples. Is there a statistical technique I can use to justify which index is better?

The data can be accessed [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/122_Ja3CyXRaKEBR-9GhNEKsa6Uw__Ejp/view?usp=sharing)

I am using R for statistical analyses.